# Autocad: export materials to FBX

Tags: textures, autocad, openscenegraph, fbx

There is a 3D-model of the premises with the set materials for surfaces designed in AutoCAD 2014. The goal is to display the model in the qt-application using the OpenSceneGraph.
As the final format chosen the FBX, as all the necessary information can be exported to it, as well as it supports both AutoCAD and openscenegraph.
When exporting I select "all objects" and "embed texture".
However, FBX Converter shows that in the file there are no textures and materials.
What could be the problem? What formats AutoCAD can export of materials and textures?
For what purpose the export in FBX use settings "embed texture"?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am not sure for AutoCAD 2014, but I think my answer will be valid anyway because I do not recall any major changes in the AutoCAD FBX exporter. The mains issues are that at the time the FBX converter was written, AutoCAD was not supporting textures the way it now supports it with the 3d objects. Another issue you need to know is that Maya still use what we call Protein material (a technology from nVidia), when exporting to FBX, we do export Protein in an encrypted binary chunk that any application having the nVidia library can read, but no one else :(.
You can eventually use the AutoCAD API to read material properties & textures and add the data during the FBX nodes' export using the FBX plug-in mechanism. Or export / bind the data into a .json file aside the fbx file. If you need help on this, contact me I can write a quick starting example to demo that.

Comment: @Popopo, did it help?